# Can not replace fragment. No view found for id for fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-fragmentactivity

I have list of fragments and artice. Every lelement on list is connected with article. That works fine. But when I try replace article by ID from external activity I have an error:`No view found for id for fragment`

**External Activity**:

```
ArticleMuralFragment newElement = new ArticleMuralFragment();
Bundle args = new Bundle();
args.putInt("ARG_POSITION", 7);
newElement.setArguments(args);

FragmentTransaction transaction = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
transaction.replace(R.id.map_container, newElement);
transaction.addToBackStack(null);
transaction.commit();
```

**XML ArticleFragment**

**LogCat**

```
12-10 20:05:28.866: E/FragmentManager(18952): No view found for id 0x7f050013 (com.urbanforms.main:id/fragment_container) for fragment ArticleMuralFragment{423009f8 #0 id=0x7f050013}
12-10 20:05:28.866: E/FragmentManager(18952): Activity state:
12-10 20:05:28.876: D/FragmentManager(18952):   Local FragmentActivity 41fb0db0 State:
12-10 20:05:28.876: D/FragmentManager(18952):     mCreated=truemResumed=true mStopped=false mReallyStopped=false
12-10 20:05:28.876: D/FragmentManager(18952):     mLoadersStarted=true
12-10 20:05:28.876: D/FragmentManager(18952):   Active Fragments in 41fb1e58:
12-10 20:05:28.876: D/FragmentManager(18952):     #0: ArticleMuralFragment{423009f8 #0 id=0x7f050013}
12-10 20:05:28.876: D/FragmentManager(18952):       mFragmentId=#7f050013 mContainerId=#7f050013 mTag=null
12-10 20:05:28.876: D/FragmentManager(18952):       mState=0 mIndex=0 mWho=android:fragment:0 mBackStackNesting=1
12-10 20:05:28.876: D/FragmentManager(18952):       mAdded=true mRemoving=false mResumed=false mFromLayout=false mInLayout=false
12-10 20:05:28.876: D/FragmentManager(18952):       mHidden=false mDetached=false mMenuVisible=true mHasMenu=false
12-10 20:05:28.876: D/FragmentManager(18952):       mRetainInstance=false mRetaining=false mUserVisibleHint=true
12-10 20:05:28.876: D/FragmentManager(18952):       mFragmentManager=FragmentManager{41fb1e58 in Map{41fb0db0}}
12-10 20:05:28.876: D/FragmentManager(18952):       mActivity=com.urbanforms.main.map.Map@41fb0db0
12-10 20:05:28.876: D/FragmentManager(18952):       mArguments=Bundle[{ARG_POSITION=7}]
12-10 20:05:28.876: D/FragmentManager(18952):   Added Fragments:
12-10 20:05:28.876: D/FragmentManager(18952):     #0: ArticleMuralFragment{423009f8 #0 id=0x7f050013}
12-10 20:05:28.876: D/FragmentManager(18952):   Back Stack Indices:
12-10 20:05:28.876: D/FragmentManager(18952):     #0: BackStackEntry{423016c0 #0}
12-10 20:05:28.876: D/FragmentManager(18952):   FragmentManager misc state:
12-10 20:05:28.876: D/FragmentManager(18952):     mActivity=com.urbanforms.main.map.Map@41fb0db0
12-10 20:05:28.886: D/FragmentManager(18952):     mContainer=android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity$2@41fb2760
12-10 20:05:28.886: D/FragmentManager(18952):     mCurState=5 mStateSaved=false mDestroyed=false
12-10 20:05:28.886: D/FragmentManager(18952):   View Hierarchy:
12-10 20:05:28.886: D/FragmentManager(18952):     com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView{41fb3958 V.E..... ... 0,0-1280,736}
12-10 20:05:28.886: D/FragmentManager(18952):       com.android.internal.widget.ActionBarOverlayLayout{41fb3fd0 V.ED.... ... 0,0-1280,736 #1020310 android:id/action_bar_overlay_layout}
12-10 20:05:28.886: D/FragmentManager(18952):         android.widget.FrameLayout{41fb4bd8 V.E..... ... 0,108-1280,736 #1020002 android:id/content}
12-10 20:05:28.886: D/FragmentManager(18952):           android.widget.RelativeLayout{41fbaa70 V.E..... ... 0,0-1280,628}
12-10 20:05:28.886: D/FragmentManager(18952):             android.widget.FrameLayout{41fbea10 V.E..... ... 0,0-1280,628 #7f050014 app:id/map}
12-10 20:05:28.886: D/FragmentManager(18952):               android.widget.FrameLayout{41f75178 V.E..... ... 0,0-1280,628}
12-10 20:05:28.886: D/FragmentManager(18952):                 maps.ae.i{41f7ebf0 VFED..C. ... 0,0-1280,628}
12-10 20:05:28.886: D/FragmentManager(18952):                 android.widget.RelativeLayout{41fffc58 V.E..... ... 0,0-1280,628}
12-10 20:05:28.886: D/FragmentManager(18952):                   android.widget.ImageView{41ffebf0 V.ED.... ... 7,593-82,621}
12-10 20:05:28.886: D/FragmentManager(18952):                 android.widget.RelativeLayout{41f86af0 V.E..... ... 0,0-1280,628}
12-10 20:05:28.886: W/ResourceType(18952): No package identifier when getting name for resource number 0x00000002
12-10 20:05:28.886: D/FragmentManager(18952):                   android.view.View{42050988 V.ED..C. ... 1211,13-1267,69 #2}
12-10 20:05:28.886: W/ResourceType(18952): No package identifier when getting name for resource number 0x00000003
12-10 20:05:28.886: D/FragmentManager(18952):                   android.widget.RelativeLayout{41ff3180 V.E..... ... 1267,82-1267,489 #3}
12-10 20:05:28.886: D/FragmentManager(18952):                     maps.bu.a{4205c660 G.ED..C. ... 0,0-0,0}
12-10 20:05:28.886: W/ResourceType(18952): No package identifier when getting name for resource number 0x00000001
12-10 20:05:28.886: D/FragmentManager(18952):                   android.widget.LinearLayout{42047d70 V.E..... ... 1211,502-1267,608 #1}
12-10 20:05:28.886: D/FragmentManager(18952):                     android.view.View{4205eba8 V.ED..C. ... 0,0-56,53}
12-10 20:05:28.886: D/FragmentManager(18952):                     android.view.View{4204b6f8 V.ED..C. ... 0,53-56,106}
12-10 20:05:28.896: D/FragmentManager(18952):         com.android.internal.widget.ActionBarContainer{41fb4fd0 V.ED.... ... 0,33-1280,108 #1020311 android:id/action_bar_container}
12-10 20:05:28.896: D/FragmentManager(18952):           com.android.internal.widget.ActionBarView{41fb54d0 V.E..... ... 0,0-1280,75 #1020312 android:id/action_bar}
12-10 20:05:28.896: D/FragmentManager(18952):             android.widget.LinearLayout{41fb5a38 VFE...C. ... 0,0-210,75}
12-10 20:05:28.896: D/FragmentManager(18952):               com.android.internal.widget.ActionBarView$HomeView{41fb6ab8 V.E..... ... 0,0-65,75}
12-10 20:05:28.896: D/FragmentManager(18952):                 android.widget.ImageView{41fb6e48 V.ED.... ... 0,27-21,48 #102025a android:id/up}
12-10 20:05:28.896: D/FragmentManager(18952):                 android.widget.ImageView{41fb71a0 V.ED.... ... 17,16-60,59 #102002c android:id/home}
12-10 20:05:28.896: D/FragmentManager(18952):               android.widget.LinearLayout{41fb8370 V.E..... ... 65,21-210,54}
12-10 20:05:28.896: D/FragmentManager(18952):                 android.widget.TextView{41fb8680 V.ED.... ... 0,0-134,33 #1020264 android:id/action_bar_title}
12-10 20:05:28.896: D/FragmentManager(18952):                 android.widget.TextView{41fb9300 G.ED.... ... 0,0-0,0 #1020265 android:id/action_bar_subtitle}
12-10 20:05:28.896: D/FragmentManager(18952):             com.android.internal.view.menu.ActionMenuView{41ff6690 V.ED.... ... 1280,0-1280,75}
12-10 20:05:28.896: D/FragmentManager(18952):           com.android.internal.widget.ActionBarContextView{41fb98d8 G.E..... ... 0,0-0,0 #1020313 android:id/action_context_bar}
12-10 20:05:28.896: D/FragmentManager(18952):         com.android.internal.widget.ActionBarContainer{41fb9da0 G.ED.... ... 0,0-0,0 #1020314 android:id/split_action_bar}
12-10 20:05:28.896: D/AndroidRuntime(18952): Shutting down VM
12-10 20:05:28.896: W/dalvikvm(18952): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x41801b90)
12-10 20:05:28.906: E/AndroidRuntime(18952): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
12-10 20:05:28.906: E/AndroidRuntime(18952): Process: com.urbanforms.main, PID: 18952
12-10 20:05:28.906: E/AndroidRuntime(18952): java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: No view found for id 0x7f050013 (com.urbanforms.main:id/fragment_container) for fragment ArticleMuralFragment{423009f8 #0 id=0x7f050013}
12-10 20:05:28.906: E/AndroidRuntime(18952):    at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:919)
12-10 20:05:28.906: E/AndroidRuntime(18952):    at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1104)
12-10 20:05:28.906: E/AndroidRuntime(18952):    at android.support.v4.app.BackStackRecord.run(BackStackRecord.java:682)
12-10 20:05:28.906: E/AndroidRuntime(18952):    at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.execPendingActions(FragmentManager.java:1467)
12-10 20:05:28.906: E/AndroidRuntime(18952):    at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl$1.run(FragmentManager.java:440)
12-10 20:05:28.906: E/AndroidRuntime(18952):    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:733)
12-10 20:05:28.906: E/AndroidRuntime(18952):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
12-10 20:05:28.906: E/AndroidRuntime(18952):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
12-10 20:05:28.906: E/AndroidRuntime(18952):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4998)
12-10 20:05:28.906: E/AndroidRuntime(18952):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
12-10 20:05:28.906: E/AndroidRuntime(18952):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
12-10 20:05:28.906: E/AndroidRuntime(18952):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:777)
12-10 20:05:28.906: E/AndroidRuntime(18952):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:593)
12-10 20:05:28.906: E/AndroidRuntime(18952):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Comment: Can you check if the fragment is still attached while you are trying to replace it?

Comment: Nothing. Forget it :) I was thinking that we can replace something only when there is a fragment already in the container. That's not the case. Sorry.

Comment: If you remove the TextView in "XML fragment container" and change the LinearLayout to FrameLayout, does that help? Lastly, is tools:context=".MainActivity" the correct context? Is the ArticleMuralFragment() class inside the MainActivity? as in inner class? If it's standalone, then context looks fine. If not it has to be ".MainActivity$ArticleMuralFragment"

Comment: 1. Doesn't  2.`ArticleMuralFragment()` is inside other `Activity`

Comment: Then, i think the context should be: tools:context="TheRelevantActivityNameWithCorrectPackageName$ArticleMuralFragment"

Comment: Dang. Can you post your entire External Activity? I am suspecting you are not inflating the XML fragment container itself now. Also, for now, take the "replace" and use "add" for the fragment transaction. You can revert it back to replace when everything is debugged and working.

Comment: @harikris my post has been edited.

Comment: Thanks. So, in your map_layout.xml, you are including your XML fragment container? Where exactly are you inflating your "XML fragment container" layout file? If you have not inflated it, then your  transaction.replace(R.id.fragment_container, newElement); will not work since the parent (R.id.fragment_container) does not exist. Makes sense?

Comment: No in map I am not including fragment container. Yea, make sense. Let my try PS. I eddited post one more time

Comment: OK. Please edit the headings to have file names so that it's easy to follow. For example, instead of "XML fragment container", have the layout file name please.

Comment: @harikris Okay, I changed headlines. Now I'm using 'add' instead of 'replace'. Tried with fragment_container and with new id created in Map.xml file. Still this same erroe

Comment: OK. I expect to see this phrase: `R.layout.HeadlineFragment`. I don't see it anywhere in your code. This means that HeadlineFragment layout does not exist physically anywhere. And hence R.id.fragment_container is crapping out. Same goes for your "Map Fragment XML". Not inflated anywhere and hence does not exist.

Comment: @harikris Should I use: `transaction.add(R.layout.HeadlineFragment, newElement);`? This same error.

Comment: :) Nope. What you need to do is in your map_layout.xml, have a place holder. Then inflate R.layout.HeadlineFragment into this placeholder. That should help. Your problem is that you have not inflated R.layout.HeadlineFragment at all and are trying to access it. HTH.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Activity from which I wanted to open Fragment had fragment defined in XML file. To replace fragment, fragment have to be defined programmatically

Comment: It would be nice if it could be explained in more detail by use of code.

Comment: Sorry, not after more than 6 years. So many things could have changed

Answer (score 2):

It seems you're using different fragment id in the code and in the Activity layout's FrameLayout id. In the code, you're using "map_container" fragment id, but the stacktrace says:

```
No view found for id 0x7f050013 (com.urbanforms.main:id/fragment_container) for fragment ArticleMuralFragment
```

Are you sure you're using the same fragment id? Because i come to the same problem when doing so. Hope this helps :)

Answer (score 1):

You are trying to put a fragment into a view container with id: fragment_container here:

```
 FragmentTransaction transaction = getSupportFragmentManager()
                                    .beginTransaction();
                            transaction.replace(R.id.fragment_container,
                                    newElement);
```

But you likely have no view with that id. Find the container view that you want this fragment to go into and give it the android:id="@+id/fragment_container tag

Comment: I have it, look onto XML HeadlineFragment

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this:

```
class UploadNewProductFragment extends Fragment{
...
...
private void repaintThisFragment() {
    FragmentManager fm = getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager();
    Fragment newFrame = new UploadNewProductFragment();
    fm.beginTransaction().replace(R.id.fragmentContainer, newFrame).commit();
}
```

Comment: and where should I invoke it?

Comment: I call this method onActivityResult(...) in the same class.

Comment: you can also move this code into FragmentActivity. in method onActivityResult(...)

Comment: what do you mean by xx?

Comment: @Serafins Check if the context is right. I have added some comment to the original question. Look it up.

Comment: I have the same problem. And your code has solved my problem. But I don't know why. Why?

Comment: @RybalkaYaroslav maybe this can help: http://developer.android.com/guide/components/fragments.html#Transactions

Answer (score 0):

Same error happened to me when I was trying to paste the code of an app I was developing without bottom navigation into a new application with bottom navigation bar. (ile, new, project with navigation activity, etc)

So for me the fragment defined in `main_activity.xml` had the id `nav_host_fragment` (instead of the id "container" that was defined in my original app without navbar), obviously, it was not going to work I realized... So I just changed the line accordingly, i.e. the line where you do the transaction?replace, I fixed it with the correct id for the fragment I was trying to replace, namely `R.id.container` to `R.id.nav_host_fragment`

Hope this helps